# Proving continuity of an integral $2$

Tags: integration

How do i prove that $f(x)$ is continuous for every $x\geq0$

I really tried to prove it with epsilon delta but failed i really need help thanks for advance.

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\int\limits_a^b f(t) &x\geq2\\f(x)=2 &x<2\end{cases}$$

where $a =  \dfrac{x}{2} $ and $b=\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right )^2$

Comment: Please make your question more clear. This is very poorly written.

Comment: As noted in my post, there is a unique function $f$ that satifies this definition. That function is continuous everywhere, and differentiable everywhere except at $x = 2$. This was put on hold as unclear prematurely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, you need to closely examine the definition of $f$. There is a unique function $f$ that satisfies these conditions.

We already know that $f(x) = 2$ on $(-\infty, 2]$. On $(2,2\sqrt 2]$, we have that $a(x) = x/2$ is less than $b(x) = x^2/4 \le 2$. So the integral is over the region where $f = 2$, and thus $$f(x) = \frac {x^2}2 - x$$

For $x \in (2\sqrt 2, 4]$, the integral is always over a region to the left of $x$, and thus already defined.

For $x > 4$, we know that $f$ satisfies an integral with smoothly varying endpoints, and thus should be differentiable. Letting $I(a,b) = \int_a^b f(t)\,dt$, we get $$\begin{align}\frac{df}{dx} &= \frac{\partial I}{\partial b}\frac{db}{dx} + \frac{\partial I}{\partial a}\frac{da}{dx}\\\ &= f\left(\frac {x^2}4\right)\frac x2 - f\left(\frac x2\right)\frac 12\end{align}$$
Rearranging $$f\left(\frac {x^2}4\right) = \frac 2x\left[f'(x) - \frac 12f\left(\frac x2\right)\right]$$
Making a substitution,
$$f(t) = \frac 1{\sqrt t}\left[f'(2\sqrt t) - \frac 12f(\sqrt t)\right]$$

Since for $t > 4$, we have $t > 2\sqrt t > \sqrt t$, this defines the value of $f$ at $t$ in terms of the value of the function and derivative at points to the left where it was already defined. By an argument similar to inductive definition, this defines $f$ everywhere.